# How to insert new tr every third iteration in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm new in node.js and Jade.

I searched for solutions without success (maybe I asked wrong questions in google, I don't know).

I want to create table rows in `each` loop in Jade. The thing is that after every 3rd `td` I want insert new `tr`. Normally it's quite simple but with Jade I simply can't achieve that.

#### My Jade file:

```
table
    thead
        tr
            td Header
    tbody
        each item, i in items
            if (i % 3 === 0)
            tr
                td
                    a(href="#{baseUrl}/admin.html?id=#{item.id}")
```

I know that something is wrong with my `if` statement. I tried many configurations without luck. I'm sure that it will be quite easy issue.

Thanks in advance for help!

#### EDIT

Based on @Laurent Perrin answer I modified a little my code. Now it creates `tr`, then 3 `td` and then new `tr` so it's a little closer...

#### New Jade

```
if (i % 3 === 0)
   tr
td: a(href="#{baseUrl}/admin.html?id=#{item.id}") dsdsd #{i}
```

#### Generated HTML

```
<tr></tr>
<td><a href="...">0</a></td>
<td><a href="...">1</a></td>
<td><a href="...">2</a></td>
<tr></tr>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: this code should do what you want, but it's not very elegant:

```
table
   thead
     tr: td Header
      tbody
        - for(var i = 0, nbRows = items.length/3; i < nbRows; i++) {
        tr
           if items[3*i]
             td: a(href="#{baseUrl}/admin.html?id=#{items[3*i].id}")
           if items[3*i + 1]
             td: a(href="#{baseUrl}/admin.html?id=#{items[3*i + 1].id}")
           if items[3*i + 2]
             td: a(href="#{baseUrl}/admin.html?id=#{items[3*i + 2].id}")
       - }
```

What you could do instead is tweak your model to make it more Jade-friendly, by grouping items by rows:

```
function getRows(items) {
    return items.reduce(function (prev, item, i) {
        if(i % 3 === 0)
            prev.push([item]);
        else
            prev[prev.length - 1].push(item);

        return prev;
    }, []);
}
```

This will turn:

```
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
```

into:

```
[
    [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}],
    [{id:4},{id:5}]
]
```

Then your jade code becomes much simpler:

```
table
     thead
         tr: td Header
     tbody
        each row in rows
            tr
                each item in row
                    td: a(href="#{baseUrl}/admin.html?id=#{item.id}")
```

Comment: This code create only thirds `tr`- first `tr`, then third, then sixth etc. What I want is create first `tr` and then 3 `td` in that `tr`. After 3 `td` new `tr` and another 3 `td` and so on.

Comment: I edited my question. Now it is a little closer to what I want achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! It is really tricky to achieve so simple task. Thanks for Your time!

Comment: I found a more elegant solution, tell me if it helps.

Comment: Oh I see. In Jade better way is to prepare data to correct display and then send to view. In PHP for example simple `if` statement in view would do the trick. Your newest version works fine and looks pretty :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An example of jade + bootstrap, each 4 elements(columns) one row, and the rows goes inside the row.

```

```
- var i = 0
- var itens_per_line = 4
each order in viewBag.orders
    - if (i % itens_per_line === 0 || i === 0) {
        .row
    - }

            .col-md-3.column
                p #{order.number}
        - i++
```

```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for a single array (e.g. ['1','2','3','4']) to convert it into two values per row, it could be adjusted for 3.

(mixins are templates in Jade/Pug)

```
        mixin mInput
          div.form-group.col-md-6
            p=oval

        - var valcounter = 0
        - var row = [];
        each val in JSON.parse(formvalues)
          if(valcounter % 2 === 0)
            - var col = [];
            - col.push(val)
          else
            - col.push(val)
            - row.push(col)
          - valcounter++
        each orow in row
          div.row
            each oval in orow
              +mInput
```